# Adjusting plot.graph_objects.Sunburst colorbar

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Although I can create a colorbar for Sunburst, I fail to manipulate the fontsize, ntick, tickvals and other parameters in the colorbar.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = dict(
    labels=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
    parents=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ],
    values=[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4],
    colors=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
)

fig = go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
    labels=data['labels'],
    parents=data['parents'],
    values=data['values'],
))

marker = fig.data[0].marker
marker.colors = data['color']
marker.colorscale = 'Blues'
marker.cmin = 0
marker.cmax = 10
marker.showscale = True

fig.update_layout(
    margin=dict(t=0, l=0, r=0, b=0),
    coloraxis_colorbar=dict(  # no response
        title='color',
        tickvals=[0, 5, 10],
        ticktext=['low', 'middle', 'high'],
        ntick=3
    ),
)
```

Is it possible to create a colorbar object and adjust the parameters from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue with the same way with `marker`, have  a look at the code below:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = dict(
    labels=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
    parents=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ],
    values=[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4],
    colors=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
)

fig = go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
    labels=data['labels'],
    parents=data['parents'],
    values=data['values'],
))

marker = fig.data[0].marker
marker.colors = data['colors']
marker.colorscale = 'Blues'
marker.cmin = 0
marker.cmax = 10
marker.showscale = True

# Add the next 4 lines
marker.colorbar.title = 'color'
marker.colorbar.tickvals = [0, 5, 10]
marker.colorbar.ticktext = ['low', 'middle', 'high']
marker.colorbar.nticks = 3 

fig.update_layout(
    margin=dict(t=0, l=0, r=0, b=0),
)


fig.show()
```

**Output**
[image]

If you want to know more about the options that you have, please look at [plotly.graph_objects.sunburst.marker package](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.sunburst.marker.html)